# How do I install s3cmd on MSYS2?

Tags: amazon-s3, msys2, s3cmd, pacman-package-manager

I'd like to install `s3cmd` in a "clean" way on MSYS2 running on Windows. But when I run

```
pacman -S s3cmd
```

nothing happens. On the other hand, I see that `s3cmd` has been packaged for ArchLinux, the Linux distribution on which MSYS2 is based:

https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/s3cmd/

So what should I do to install `s3cmd` on MSYS2?

Comment: This does not look like a programming question.

Comment: MSYS2 isn't really based on Arch Linux, it just borrows its package manager and tends to use similar package names.  It has a separate [package recipe repository](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages) which is smaller than Arch Linux's because most programs require a bunch of work to get them working on Windows.  MSYS2 only has the packages that someone took the time to port over to MSYS2.  If you can't find your package in that repository, or by running `pacman -Ss s3cmd`, or poking around in http://repo.msys2.org/ , then it has not been made yet.